# Passing and rendering components based on entity type in React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I've encountered a problem with types in TypeScript. I want to pass an array of `items` with a `contentType` field and related component `props` to the root component. In the root component, I want to render a specific component for each item depending on the `contentType` and pass all the props from `item.props`, but I'm facing a type mismatch.

So, currently I came up with such code, but I'm getting an error when calling a mapped component: `<Component {...props}/>`:

```
Type '{ bar: number; } | { foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { bar: number; } & { foo: string; }'.
  Property 'foo' is missing in type '{ bar: number; }' but required in type '{ foo: string; }'.
```

It appears that `props` can refer to both components, and a `Component` can belong to either of the two without any connection between them.

```
const FirstComponent = ({bar}: {bar: number}) => {
    return <div>{bar}</div>
}
const SecondComponent = ({foo}: {foo: string}) => {
    return <div>{foo}</div>
}

type Item = {
    contentType: 'one'
    props: ComponentProps<typeof FirstComponent>
} | {
    contentType: 'two'
    props: ComponentProps<typeof SecondComponent>
}

type ComponentMap = {
    one: typeof FirstComponent
    two: typeof SecondComponent
}
const componentMap: ComponentMap = {
    one: FirstComponent,
    two: SecondComponent
}

type RootProps = {
    items: Item[]
}

const Root = ({ items }: RootProps) => {
    return (
        <div>{items.map(({ contentType, props }) => {
            const Component = componentMap[contentType]
            return <Component {...props} />
        })}</div>
    )
}

// ========================================

const items: Item[] = [
    {contentType: 'one', props: {bar: 12}},
    {contentType: 'two', props: {foo: 'str'}}
]

const Home = () => {
    return <Root items={items}/>
}
```